# Making message passing work in Chrome With Injected Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a Chrome plugin (76.0.3809.132 version of Chrome) that:

1. Injects a JavaScript block in a web page (done)
2. Get the injected block to pass back message to the chrome plugin using the latest Chrome runtime functionality (problem)

I initially referred to the Chrome developer reference at: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage

Accordingly, my Manifest is:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Message Passing",
  "description": "Simple messaging plugin",
  "version": "1.1",

  "externally_connectable": {
   "matches": ["*://*.myexample.com/*"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "*://*.myexample.com/*"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.myexample.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["myContent.js"]
    }
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": ["injected.js"]
}
```

My content script:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('injected.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
//injecting correctly till this point
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            console.log("In plugin");//never gets called
});
```

JavaScript within the web page that makes the call to plugin:

```
//the function called by my web page, sending a JSON or text message
async function sendMessageToPlugin(dataToSend){
    console.log('Send to plugin');//this is getting printed
    var extID = 'abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc';
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extID, dataToSend);
}
```

No error, no result. I have tried different things, trying to create a background script to listen instead of listening in content script, trying to create a port for persistent messages instead, using "onMessage" instead of "onMessageExternal" per various older posts on the forum, but nothing works :(. What am I doing wrong? Can somebody at least point me towards any actually working example of a web page successfully communicating with the Chrome plugin? Would be good to know what Manifest was used and which part of the extension listened to the message successfully (content script or background). Thank you for your help!

***Update 1:***
I had some success with using the method described at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication. Is this the only way of doing this? I would prefer to do it using externally connected functionality, but happy to keep testing this method and run with it if it works.

**Update 2:**
This code finally works for me:

In my content script-

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    // We only accept messages from ourselves
    if (event.source != window)
        return;

    //if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {
    console.log("Content script received: ");
    console.log(event.data);
    //}
}, false);
```

And in my injected script:

```
async function sendMessageToPlugin(dataToSend) {
    console.log('Send to plugin');        
    window.postMessage(dataToSend, "*");
}
```

I am sure Jafar's solution will work as well (I will try it and update!), but for now I am sticking with this one. Thank you Jafar for taking out time to reply!

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessageExternal) says onMessageExternal cannot be used in a content script. You need to move it into your [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).